# How to copy exactly in tcl?

Tags: tcl

I created a list using:

```
set list1 { o\\/one o\\/two o\\/three }
```

now I want to copy this list to another list by adding { } to each item
my new list should become :

```
{ {o\\/one} {o\\/two} {o\\/three} }
```

I tried using

```
foreach a $list1 {
    set x "{$a}"
    append new_list " " "{$a}"
    lappend new_list1 $x
}
```

`newlist` →  `{o\/one} {o\/two} {o\/three}`

`newlist1` → `{{o\/one}} {{o\/two}} {{o\/three}}`

Please help?

Comment: I think this is an XY problem: you think you can solve your problem by adding braces so you're asking how to do tthat. I have a feeling your original problem can be solved in a more straightforward way. Can you take a step. back and describe the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original list has these items in it (as you can verify with `lindex`):

1. `puts [lindex $list1 0]` → `o\/one`
2. `puts [lindex $list1 1]` → `o\/two`
3. `puts [lindex $list1 2]` → `o\/three`

*Any* list that has those elements in it, *however encoded,* is pairwise-equivalent. The canonical form (as produced by Tcl's own list operations) of the list is:

`{o\/one} {o\/two} {o\/three}`

Perhaps the easiest way of obtaining that is:

```
set list2 [lrange $list1 0 end]
```

The `lrange` command uses Tcl's standard list-to-string engine (shared with a great many other commands). That prefers to *not* add braces, but prefers adding braces to adding backslashes; backslashes are a last resort because they're ugly and hard to read. But it works with arbitrary contents in the elements; just blindly adding braces is vulnerable to tricky edge cases.

Another way of getting the above canonical form is this (provided you're not stuck on versions of Tcl so old they're no longer supported):

```
set list2 [list {*}$list1]
```

---

[EDIT]: If you've got a string with some things in it separated by spaces, you might want to convert it into a proper list; this is useful particularly when the input data contains list metacharacters like braces and (relevant in this case) backslashes. There are two main ways to do this:

1. `set theList [split $inputString]`
2. `set theList [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $inputString]`

They differ in what happens when the input string has two (or more) spaces between two words:

```
set inputString "a b  c d";                    # NB: two spaces between b and c
puts [split $inputString];                     # ==> a b {} c d
puts [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $inputString]; # ==> a b c d
```

*There are use-cases for both.*

Comment: I did understand your point. What I am not able to understand is that when I am doing
`puts $list1`
then it is printing 
`o\\/one o\\/two o\\/three`
But when I am printing individual list item it prints 
`o\/one`

Is there a way that I can preserve both the backslashes while copying it in another list and add curly braces to it

Comment: In that case you have a string with some things in it separated by spaces, not _formally_ a Tcl list. `split` it (or use `regexp -all -inline {\S+}` if there are multi-space separators) to convert into a true Tcl list. Then the words you get out will be the words you expect (though the overall list might not look like what you expect).